# Why are there only one of each kind of NODE in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Why are there only one of each kind of NODE as NAMENODE, SNAMENODE, DATANODE in HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

In HA setup, you wouldn't have a secondary namenode, so let's exclude that.

What you call "kind" is just a name. Datanodes and Standby namenodes can (and should) have more than one of them deployed.